# Calculating the required DTU for individual databases

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are considering to move our production databases to Azure SQL database. As part of the initial investigation, we used the [Azure SQL Database DTU Calulater](https://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/) to estimate the DTU required.

The counter estimates the total DTU required to migrate all database to Azure. However, for the cost estimation, I was asked to measure DTU required for individual databases.

Is it possible, what is the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use the Azure SQL database, you first need to create a Azure SQL Server which host your databases. Then you can configure the database.

You used the Azure SQL Database DTU Calulater to estimate the DTU required, and this calulater is for single database and Elastic Databases.

The counter estimates the DTU required to migrate a single database to Azure, not all databases.

It means that each database may requires different DTUs. How many databases you have, how many times you need to calculate.

Then you can configure the database `DTUs` and `Data max size` on Azure Portal according the calculation result. Every time when you deploy your database to Azure SQL Server, you all need to configure the database.

**Create Azure database**:
[image]

**Configure Database**:
[image]

You also can reference this blog: [Azure DTU Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517626/azure-dtu-calculation/53811307#53811307)

Actually, what you said in comment is right. For example you have 40 databases, and each database requires 10 DTUs.,it's pirce tier is S0. You must pay for Azure S0x40.

For exampe:

I have three database in my Azure SQL server, S2(50DTU),BASIC(5DTU) and S0(10DTU):
[image] 
That's mean that I need pay it according the each database price tier.

For more details, please see: [Service tiers in the DTU-based purchase model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu).

You can get the total DTUs on Azure SQL Server DTU quota:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Apart from Database - Log Bytes Flushed/sec counter all other are server level counters. How can this be correct for a single database?. As per the calculator, we should choose s10. We have 40 databases, does this mean 40XS10?

Comment: Hi,@user1716729, if my answer helps you, can you accept it? Thanks and have a good day!